# Show index of each string in a list

Tags: python

I wish to find the index of each integer(I converted it to string since I do not know any alternate ways) in a list.

Example, I have a list:

```
a = [0,3,3,7,5,3,11,1] # My list
a = list(map(str, a)) # I map it to string for each integer in the list, is there any better way than this? I would like to learn

for x in a: # I then loop each str in the list
    print(a.index(x)) # here I print each index of the str
```

My output is:

```
0
1
1
3
4
1
6
7
```

My expected output should be:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

Comment: `for i in range(len(list)): print(i)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for `enumerate()`

```
a = ['apple', 'ball', 'cat']

for i, it in enumerate(a):
    print(i)

>>> output
0
1
2
```

Answer (score 1):

`.index()` is not used for showing its original index but the first index that matches the value you passed into.

You can use `enumerate` to get both the index and the value in the list.

```py
a = [0,3,3,7,5,3,11,1]
for index, value in a:
    print('{} {}'.format(index, value))
```

And not sure why you wanted to convert a to a list of strings instead of integers?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Python's built-in function `enumerate()`.

In your case you can do:

```
a = [0,3,3,7,5,3,11,1] 

for index, element in enumerate(a):
    print index
```

The output should be:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

You can check the documentation in this [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate).